# How to access instance variable inside lazy variable declaration swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and was trying to understand lazy variable. I have working experience on Objective-C but swift is driving me crazy.

I have core data model. Where `Person` ----holds----> `Account` and `Account` ----belongsTo--> `Person`. `holds` and `belongsTo` are the relationship.

`Person` list will be displayed and on tapping person all the account associated with him should be listed in TableView. I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` because account might get added on the fly and I want to reflect the changes immediately using `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate.

Now I have passed tapped person object to my class.

```
class DetailViewController : ViewController{
    var foundPerson : Person?

    lazy var accountFetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController = {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AccountInfo")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "belongsTo = %@", foundPerson!)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "accountnumber", ascending: true)]
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appdelegate!.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    //other view controller methods
}
```

When I try to compile this it gives error saying that

> "Instance member foundPerson can not be used on type
>   DetailViewController"

I could not understand much from that error. What exactly is it trying to convey ?? Whats the mistake ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding self before foundPerson

```
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "belongsTo = %@", self.foundPerson!)
```

Comment: Bingo buddy :) Got the answer :) I was about to delete my question and saw ur answer :) Thank you :) I'll accept ur answer in 8 min (Cant accept the answer as I have up voted it just now)